# How can I get the token in Firebase cloud messaging (FCM Token for the user)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Ive been trying to get a push notification system running using firebase cloud messaging and have got a lot of the parts working, however I cannot find the token to send the user the notification. Im not hosting this on anything yet and currently its localhost.

Ive tried `console.log(currentToken)`, `console.log(getToken)` but they both seem to not work (Seems to because the codes that people get look fimiliar, but when I use postman to send a POST it doesnt work and returns INVALID_KEY. So im assuming its something with the way im getting the key).
Error: INVALID_KEY
Error 401

**Postman Configuration:**

*Header*:

```
KEY: Authorization
VALUE: key=BAuk8x3jiOJ1w6wgCZGi1vvluYKON6127b9ps5M...
KEY: Content-Type
VALUE: application/json
```

*Body*:

```
{
  "to": "cgiiobJJ_4bUf3LrF9V8ce:APA91bErIPl1c4_2WH8BSfKp2zw93JkDCovjYiezaq...",
  "notification": {
    "body": "New announcement assigned",
    "OrganizationId": "2",
    "content_available": true,
    "priority": "high",
    "subtitle": "Elementary School",
    "title": "hello"
  },
  "data": {
    "priority": "high",
    "sound": "app_sound.wav",
    "content_available": true,
    "bodyText": "New Announcement assigned",
    "organization": "Elementary school"
  }
}
```

*I HAVE REMOVED PARTS OF THE TOKENS BTW*

**Heres the code:**

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = getMessaging(app);

getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: 'VAP_KEY_HERE' }).then( async (currentToken) => {
    if (currentToken) {
      // Send the token to your server and update the UI if necessary
      console.log(getToken);
      console.log(currentToken);
      // ...
    } else {
        console.log('Requesting permission...');
        Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
          if (permission === 'granted') {
            console.log('Notification permission granted.');
      console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
    // ...
  });
};
});
```

This has returned codes that look like they should work but in postman I simply get INVALID_KEY from google FCM

Comment: Since the error occurs in Postman, can you also show the minimal code to reproduce the problem in that. While at it, please also show the exact, complete error message - in case there's more than `INVALID_KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I did some more digging and turns out I was using the Vapid key as the authorization key for PostMan.
To fix simply enable Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) and use the Server key found there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).